# Why might MonoDevelop 2.4 not start on a PowerPC Mac running Tiger

Tags: macos, monodevelop, powerpc

I am trying to get MonoDevelop 2.4 to run on a PowerPC Mac running Tiger.

I have downloaded Mono 2.4.3 from the "older releases" page off the download page and installed it. I have downloaded the OS X MonoDevelop 2.4 package and installed it. When I run it is doesn't start - it bounces up and down in the dock for a bit and then disappears. The stack trace in the console log is:

Mac OS X Version 10.4.11 (Build 8S165)
2010-09-24 14:45:13 +0100
2010-09-24 14:45:17.383 SystemUIServer[174] lang is:en
Stacktrace:

at MonoDevelop.Core.Properties.Get (string) <0xffffffff>
  at MonoDevelop.Core.Properties.Get (string) <0x000cc>
  at MonoDevelop.Core.Properties.Set (string,object) <0x00048>
  at MonoDevelop.Core.PropertyService..cctor () <0x00188>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdePreferences.get_UserInterfaceTheme () <0xffffffff>
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdePreferences.get_UserInterfaceTheme () <0x00038>
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (string[]) <0x0092c>
  at MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main (string[]) <0x000b0>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.runtime_invoke_int_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

I have done some web searching and one suggestion was that MD requires the CSDK but I can't find a link for the 2.4.3 version of that. Another is that MD is being run in debug mode by the launch script and that has caused other Mac ppc owners problems however that doesn't seem to be the case in the script for version 2.4.

Should this combination of software and OS work? if so, what else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a native Mono crash. Unfortunately PPC isn't very well supported as very few people now have PPC machines. If you could try running it in gdb and capturing the trace, then filing a bug against Mono, that would help.